# Is there a good WPF pivot control?

Tags: wpf, controls

Does anyone have any experience with a good wpf pivot table control?

Answer (score 8):

[DevExpress Grid control](http://www.devexpress.com/Products/NET/Controls/WPF/Grid/) has good pivot functionality. Used it for Winforms a lot. I think the WPF version is also available.

Comment: A native WPF pivot grid is available http://devexpress.com/Products/NET/Controls/WPF/Pivot_Grid/

Answer (score 1):

The [Xceed WPF Grid](http://xceed.com/Grid_WPF_Intro.html) looks like it has a lot of great capabilities.  We use their WinForms grid and it does a pretty good job.  They have a demo app you can download that shows off the different ways you can use the grid.

Comment: Not a pivot control, and they are not planning adding any pivot functionality (cording to forums)

Answer (score 1):

VIBlend's [data grid control](http://www.viblend.com/products/winforms/gridview.aspx) has pivot table capabilities. I'm not sure if they have a WPF version but you can certainly host WinForms controls in WPF. Another alternative is to try hosting the MS Office OWC.

Comment: They have now a Silverlight Grid and planning a WPF one.

Comment: Update: They released to WPF version.

Answer (score 0):

If possible, I also need to be able to drag column headers and make them row headers and have the data summarize and group accordingly.  Something along the lines of old ActiveX DataDynamics Dynamicube.

http://www.datadynamics.com/Products/ProductOverview.aspx?Product=DC

Auto Summary, Filtering of the Data Items being used, etc.  without having to write a lot of code to do it in a custom fashion.

Comment: Yes it has those features http://www.devexpress.com/Products/NET/Controls/WinForms/Grid/dataoperations.xml

Answer (score 0):

Alternative:
[Excel OWC](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?familyid=7287252c-402e-4f72-97a5-e0fd290d4b76&displaylang=en) is a great query and reporting tool if you are running OLAP. It's a little dated and poorly documented, but works well on the intranet and can squeak by over the net.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc164070.aspx

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest [WPF Toolkit](http://www.codeplex.com/wpf/Release/ProjectReleases.aspx?ReleaseId=14963) which can be downloaded from DatGrid available in Codeplex. This is compatible with the latest WPF(.NET3.5 SP1) which is free and have almost all the features for a general purpose(and even more than that) But there are commercial vendors who have good grid controls(Not really free). Like Xceed, Infragistics, Component One, Telerik

Answer (score 0):

Currently there are no WPF Pivot Grid controls.  The vendor most likely to have it, DevExpress does not yet have a WPF version of the XtraPivotGrid.

Your best bet is to use XtraPivotGrid hosted inside your WPF control.

The other thing you can do is to use another grid vendor and do the "pivoting" by using LINQ or by manipulating the DataTable manually.

Answer (score 0):

[DevExpress Pivot Grid for WPF](http://devexpress.com/Home/Announces/Roadmap-2010.xml#wpf) is almost ready. It will be released in the first half of the year.

Answer (score -1):

I am a consultant at Infragistics and I've been working exclusively the last few weeks with the Infragistics XamPivotGrid. We've been working to make this control fast and memory efficient. As a user and a developer, I am highly impressed with the usability of this control. You can check out this control in the WPF and the Silverlight NetAdvantage Data Visualization products at www.infragistics.com!

:-)